# Will Esri’s Road Closures solution perform a reverse geocode to get Waze street names?

Tags: arcgis-local-government, waze

We are new to the Waze for Cities program. Currently, I am trying to get information regarding how to submit road closure data to Waze using [Road Closure](https://community.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsolutions.arcgis.com%2Flocal-government%2Fhelp%2Froad-closures) solution. I read all the documentation for this solution, as well as the guidelines provided by Waze for this task. Being an Esri shop, we want to use this tool rather than Waze Map Editor since WME will not work for our workflow.

I noticed that Waze Map Editor tool will auto-populate the street name information when creating road closures. Since we are using the Esri solution tool for Waze, that is, the web mapping application for road closures, street names are not auto populated. As you may know, the streets shown in the Esri’s base map may vary from Waze basemap street names. **Will Esri’s solution perform a reverse geocode operation using as an input the geometry delineated in the web map to get Waze street names?**

**See here:** https://developers.google.com/waze/data-feed/problem-resolution#reverse-geocoding-api

Answer (score 2):

The Road Closures solution does not do a reverse geocode against the Waze api to pull the street name. It uses the Smart Editor widget which can be configured to do a reverse geocode against an Esri locator to pull information into a field automatically when a feature is created, but it can't be configured to use the Waze api.